# Stuck in USB-debugging mode

Tags: usb-connection-mode, htc-one-x, usb-debugging

I turned on usb-debugging on my HTC One X just to see if I could identify it when using Android SDK. Now the usb-debugging mode always shows up when I connect the phone to my Windows and Linux computer.

I have Android 4.1.1 on it; it's not rooted. The settings in developer options is off for everything. Developer options itself is also set to off. Despite this, I always get a notification on my phone that it has connected in usb-debugging mode when I connect with usb-cable. When I check the developer options, they are mysteriously set to on again.

When I try to change the settings for the usb connection, I get the settings for Portable hotspot & tethering and not the settings to charge or use mass storage. Strange!

This behavior prevents me from using the mass storage option. On my Linux computer, I cannot see any files on the device.

Are there any global configurations/settings I can clear to fix this? What else should/could I do?

Comment: [This XDA developers thread may be relevant](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2090699)

Comment: Did you update the phone. The mass storage option is no longer available. You are connected in MTP

Comment: Community bump prevention: this question was closed because the question seems to have been abandoned (OP hasn't visited the network for more than 5 years, and no answers have score above 0). If anyone can evaluate the existing answers, feel free to vote accordingly and reopen the question (or mod-flag the question requesting for reopening). For anyone else having the same issue, please post a new question and refer to this question as additional context.

Answer (score 0):

In the developer settings, there is a "Revoke USB debugging authorizations". Try to use it. It should remove the authorization you give for your computer. So next time, that computer won't be able to directly use the debugging.

Comment: This sounds smart. OP should give it a go.